# Some cells in Android GridView doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a strange bug with Grid View which I'm not quite sure where to start checking. As I scroll the GridView up, one of the cells would stop scrolling as it reach the top of grid view. If I continue scroll up, that cell would be covered by the row below it.

If necessary, I can post the adapter code here, but it contains quite a bit code.

Thanks.

Comment: `but it contains quite a bit code`: more code == higher probability of error

Comment: Also, posting code == higher probability that we can help :)

Comment: You'll need to post your code so that we can help debug it.

Comment: Actually I found out why. There's an obscure drawing bug in the view class that I use in the cells of grid view. Can we mark this question closed?